# how to access a parent variable from a inner nested test in junit5

Tags: junit, junit5

```
public class A{
   public String foo = null;

   @Test
   void assignValueToFoo(){
       foo = "foo";
   }

  @Nested
  class B{
     @BeforeEach
     void doSomethingBeforeEachTest(){
         assertNotNull(foo);
     }
  }
}
```

I need to access the foo variable in class B without using a @BeforeEach in class A, how can I get the value of variable foo in class B?

Comment: Your code works on my computer as expected. Foo is null since every test is dealt a new instance of the inner and outer test class. What behaviour would you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described is the expected behavior.

If you don't want to perform the assignment of the `foo` field in a `@BeforeEach` method in `A`, your only option is to annotate `A` with `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` so that the instance of `A` is reused while executing tests in `B`.